# Eureka Server connectivity issues

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am facing an issue when connecting to a remote Eureka Server from the discovery client app running on my laptop. The configuration is

1. Eureka Server is running as a standalone app and started using java -jar on a remote VM.
2. I am able to access the dashboard from my browser successfully!
3. To access the dashboard from curl, I am having to specify a http_proxy. This leads me to believe that the browser is resolving the proxy automagically...
4. Attempt to access the endpoint from my discovery client app gives a timeout error. I have tried starting the discovery client from my IDE and from command line by specifying the proxy and both haven't worked.

Stacktrace:

```
2018-07-02 11:27:19,945 [nfoReplicator-0] ERROR   c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(ln:83) - Request execution error
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080 timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.7.2.jar!/:1.7.2]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.register(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:56) ~[eureka-client-1.7.2.jar!/:1.7.2]
```

Can someone please guide me to what checks/changes can I try to attempt resolving this issue? I do have complete control of the remote VM if there are any checks to be run.

**EDIT-1**

Dashboard URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/abcd/services/discovery-server/

Service url in Discovery Client: 
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=   http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080/abcd/services/discovery-server/eureka

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to eureka-netflix but to me it seems like service URL is incorrect. Ideally it should be like-

http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/

Assuming you are running it on port 8080, it should be-

http://your_host_name:8080/eureka/